# Selected Time + 1440 Minutes

Tags: php, mysql

```
$buldurt=mysql_query("SELECT MIN(tarih) FROM kupon WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , tarih, now( ) )<1440 AND oynanma='1' AND uyeisim='$session'");
$buldurtx=mysql_fetch_array($buldurt);
```

This is giving me the TIMESTAMP value that I need first. I want to print;

$buldurtx[0] + 1440 minutes = TIMESTAMP THAT I NEED.

How can I solve that problem, I could not find :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(tarih) + INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE) FROM ...
```

Comment: This gave me a result like : "1346717330"

Comment: SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(tarih) + INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE) FROM kupon WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , tarih, now( ) )<1440 AND oynanma='1' AND uyeisim='$session'

Comment: @Slavez: That's the timestamp of the result.  What were you expecting?

Comment: Ah, my silliness. Thanks a lot!